# getting the number of filtered results in a listgrid (smartgwt)

Tags: java, smartgwt

I'm having a listgrid filled with entries, with filtering enabled. when I execute the filter the listgrid gets updated accordingly. Now I want to get the number of results that were found with the filters. I tried adding the `FilterEditorSubmitHandler` but that gets executed before the filter is actually executed (and also the `listGrid.getDataSource().getFields()` always returns `0`.

Is there a way to get the number of results **after** the filter was applied? to be more precise: the `FilterEditorSubmitHandler` is called before the actual filtering, and I need a handler that gets called after the filter was applied, or right after the grid was updated again

Comment: Can you provide code snippet showing how you execute the filter?

Comment: i provided some code in this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100449/using-wildcards-in-a-filter-for-listgrid-smartgwt . i just use the built-in functionality that comes w/ smartgwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the correct handler.

the `DataArrivedHandler` works after a filter is executed and gets the correct number of results. On the first fill of the `ListGrid` it returns 0 though, but when filling the DataSource I already know the size of the `Set` I retrieve.

as a side note: I'm using an RPC call to get the data out of the DB, and not the SmartGWT server stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following:

```
grid.getRecords();
grid.getRecordList();
grid.getResultSet();
grid.getDataAsRecordList();
```

Comment: ok, thanks. but what handler is to use in order to get the already filtered number. the FilterEditorSubmitHandler is called before the actual filtering, and I need one that gets called after the filter was applied, or right after the grid was updated again.

Comment: I think you should post it as a separate question. & if you do so, provide its link here.

Comment: I intended this in the question already, I will rephrase my question to be more clear

Comment: @gpapaz, Is this question for me?